# Rails 5 - knock for JWT not working when route namespaced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Knock for JWT authentication for Rails 5 API.

I have this Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
        namespace :v1 do
            post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
        end
    end
end
```

With this, I expect to be able to make a POST request to create new token like this:

> POST http://api.domain.com/v1/user_token

but this request gives me the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant API::V1::User

What I can understand is that Knock is trying to access the model `User` on the same namespace where the controller (`user_token_controller`) is. But my model are not namespaced:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  #...
end
```

My user_token_controller.rb

```
module API
    module V1
        class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
        end
    end
end
```

What I dong wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug already [fixed](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/commit/ed467d1e3e70dde5b4a367ac1b73dcf48ae4cebb) but not yet published.

The temporary solution was using the gem from github code like:

> gem 'knock', github: 'psantos10/knock', branch: 'master'

https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/120